# Can't see Internet Radio in iTunes Libary despite it being checked in preferences

Tags: itunes, macos

How do I make it visible?

iTunes 11.1.5
OSX 10.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have enabled it, you should see it as shown on the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Actually I now realise I meant in the sidebar. The preferences dialog states 'Library' and the sidebar states 'Library' so you'd think that the two would be identical dependent on selection

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning off internet radio and turning it back on via preferences?

Have you also tried quitting `iTunes.app` and restarting it (with/without the preference selected)? I just tried, and it worked in all of these cases on my Mac (rMBP, OS X 10.9.2, iTunes 11.1.5(5) (64-bit).

Comment: Yes and yes. See my other comment about the sidebar.

Comment: I believe that you’re just stuck with Music —> “Internet”. I don’t think that there’s a way (currently) to get the “Internet Radio” feature to show up in the sidebar.